# Development API for node JS Acceptance Tests

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, mocking, acceptance-testing

I have created acceptance tests for my library. When the library is published it will be using an external API service which is not yet accessible. So I have created a mock json api server which returns the required JSON to test against. What I have to do to get the tests to pass is change the API url manually in the file where the request is made.

I am wondering if there is a way to use the mock API url when running the acceptance tests and reverting back to the live URL when not running the acceptance tests. Below is a snippet of the code with a live URL.

```
return fetch('http://liveURL.com/api')
  .then(response => {
    if (response.status === 200) {
      return response.json()
        .then(myResponse => {
          var theResponse = myResponse.id;

          return theResponse;
        });
    } else {
      return response.json().then(error => {
        throw new Error(error.error);
      });
    }
  });
```

What I want to do when running the acceptance tests only is change the url, 'http://liveURL.com/api', I'm getting the request from to 'http://localhost:3000/api'.

The mock server I am using can be found here: https://github.com/typicode/json-server

EDIT: In reply to Bens questions, Here is my package.json where I am trying to set the NODE_ENV

```
{
  "name": "my-lib",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "lib/myLib",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "gulp lint",
    "pretest": "npm run lint",
    "test": "istanbul cover node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha -- --reporter spec \"test/unit/**/*.spec.js\"",
    "acceptance-test": "NODE_ENV=test cucumberjs",
    "build": "gulp build"
  },
  "author": "Me",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.16.3",
    "babelify": "^7.3.0",
    "browserify": "^13.1.0",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "chai-as-promised": "^5.3.0",
    "config-browserify": "^1.0.5",
    "cors": "^2.8.1",
    "cucumber": "^0.10.3",
    "eslint": "^3.0.1",
    "eslint-teamcity": "^1.1.0",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-eslint": "^3.0.1",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.6.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^2.0.0",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "istanbul": "v1.1.0-alpha.1",
    "jsdom": "^9.8.3",
    "json-server": "^0.9.1",
    "mocha": "^2.5.3",
    "mocha-jsdom": "^1.1.0",
    "mocha-teamcity-reporter": ">=0.0.1",
    "nock": "^9.0.0",
    "node-localstorage": "^1.3.0",
    "portscanner": "^2.1.0",
    "proxyquire": "^1.7.10",
    "selenium-server": "^2.53.0",
    "selenium-webdriver": "^2.53.2",
    "semver": "^5.3.0",
    "serve-static": "^1.11.1",
    "sinon": "^1.17.4",
    "sinon-chai": "^2.8.0",
    "vinyl-buffer": "^1.0.0",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0",
    "watchify": "^3.7.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "config": "^1.21.0"
  }
}
```

I have created my two servers in world.js. One server to run the library on which is on port 23661 and one server where the fake api is on which is port 3000. This can be seen below

```
'use strict';

const SeleniumServer = require('selenium-webdriver/remote').SeleniumServer;
 const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
const server = new SeleniumServer(require('selenium-server').path, {port: 4444});
const serveStatic = require('serve-static');
const express = require('express');
const chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');
const chai = require('chai');
const jsonServer = require('json-server');
const cors = require('cors');

chai.should();
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);

const testServer = jsonServer.create();
const router = jsonServer.router('db.json');

testServer.use(cors());
testServer.options('*', cors());
testServer.use(router);
testServer.listen(3000);

const app = express();
const httpServerPort = 23661;
app.use(cors());
app.options('*', cors());
app.use(serveStatic('dist'));
app.use(serveStatic(__dirname + '/../page'));
app.use(serveStatic('node_modules/sinon/pkg'));
app.listen(httpServerPort);

server.start();
```

When this is run it runs through the acceptance tests correctly in firefox browser.

The file where I am trying to call

```
process.env.NODE_ENV
```

is in my minimised library call myLib.min.js.

Here is part of the unminified file

```
'use strict';

const fetch = require('isomorphic-fetch');

module.exports = id => {
  var apiUrl = 'http://liveurl.com/api/' + id;

  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    apiUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/api';
  }

  console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV);

    return fetch(apiUrl)
      .then(response => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
          return response.json()
            .then(myResponse => {
              var theResponse = myResponse.id;

              return theResponse;
            });
        } else {
          return response.json().then(error => {
            throw new Error(error.error);
          });
        }
      });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is generally solved by the use of [environment variables](https://davidwalsh.name/node-environment-variables).

Something like:

```
var apiUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/api'
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  apiUrl = 'http://liveurl.com/api';
}

return fetch(apiUrl)
  .then(response => {
  //... and so on
```

Then you would start your app (or run your tests) like this, filling in the appropriate environment name for NODE_ENV. Common values are production|test|development:

```
NODE_ENV=production node ./path/to/app.js
```

Comment: Thanks, So I am starting my test servers in world.js with the command 'npm run acceptance-test', so would it be in world.js where I set the NODE_ENV?

Comment: No, you would run `NODE_ENV=test npm run acceptance-test`

Comment: ok so I have `"acceptance-test": "NODE_ENV=development cucumbers"` in my package.json. Now when I run `npm run acceptance-test` this will run my tests with `NODE_ENV` set to 'development'? However when I add `console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV)` to my code before the if statement you provided it says it is `undefined`.

Comment: Hm... That's odd. Can you share a gist of your package.json and your test file?

Comment: Just a heads-up that this goes against a commonly accepted methodology described by the "Twelve Factor App." A less _smelly_ solution would be the set an `API_URL` env var, and just use whatever's there, rather than switching on `NODE_ENV`. :)